# Why selenium wont open my chrome profile?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

My selenium driver wont open my chrome profile. Chrome drivers are same with my chrome version. It just opens clean browser.

Here is code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/rektl/Desktop/csdd projekts/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Rektl/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2")

browser.get("https://google.com")
```

Some error codes if that will help:

```
[8052:3876:0303/141810.953:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:18:10.953] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[8052:3876:0303/141810.965:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:18:10.965] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[8052:3988:0303/141810.995:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
```

Comment: first add arguaments to options, then assign driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Copy profile path from chrome://version/

e.g. C:\Users\pcuser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

```
        opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        opt.binary_location = r'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'    
        chromedriver_exe_location = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'chromedriver.exe')  
        profile_path = r'C:\\Users\\pcuser\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data' # path minus last folder
        opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir={}'.format(profile_path))
        opt.add_argument('--profile-directory={}'.format('DEFAULT')) # last folder name
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_exe_location, options=opt, service_args='')
```

Comment: Yay! It did work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `optins` but added the values there only after creating the web driver instance so this will have no effect.
You should put the line

```py
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Rektl/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2")
```

Before

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/rektl/Desktop/csdd projekts/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Please try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/Rektl/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/rektl/Desktop/csdd projekts/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

browser.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: unfortunately it still opens clean google browser, maybe there is something to do with permissions, because in selenium created browser i cant login in my google account, it shows that browser is not secure.

Comment: I'm sorry, I never actually used my chrome profile with Selenium